# Ionization Through Atomic Collisions - Any Reason(s) for Its being Unimportant?

Tags: physical-chemistry

The dominant processes which contribute to the ionisation of a gas (which is possibly hot and dense) are often deemed to be electron-impact ionization ($A + e^- \rightarrow A^+ + e^- + e^-$) and photo-ionisation (e.g. illumination of a sample by laser).

Are there any reasons why ionisation through atomic collisions is unimportant, especially in the case when a gas is dense (i.e. $A + A \rightarrow A^+ + e^- + A$)? Are there any readily available data (e.g. "atomic"-impact ionisation cross sections e.t.c.) to assess its magnitude? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To ionize an atom energy has to be supplied to free the electron. This energy is of order 10 ev    per scatter. The atoms in a gas have an [average kinetic energy which defines the temperature of the gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Three_neutrino_probabilities) and the [distribution is given by statistical mechanics.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/disfcn.html#c2)

[Here is the ionization energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/chemical/ionize.html) needed for a number of gases:

[image: ionener]

Compare to :

> [The thermal energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28energy%29) in each degree of freedom of a molecule at 25 °C (kT/2) (0.01 eV)

When considering also the [Maxwell Boltzman distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MaxwellBoltzmann-en.svg), this factor of 1000 can only be overcome by very few molecules . In addition the  probability of a collision to transfer all the high tail kinetic energy and eject an electron is small. It is only at high temperatures that [a plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_%28physics%29) can be sustained by collisions within the gas itself.

Comment: By chance- do you know how I would turn this into a cross-section for ionization?

Comment: This explanation is not entirely correct. The kinetic energy of an electron is the _same_ as that of an atom, and is of the order $kT$. The rate of ionization is proportional to $<v \sigma>$, where $<...>$ denotes the average over the Maxwell distribution, $v$ the velocity of the (impacted) electron/particle, and $\sigma$ the cross-section. It's true that v is dependent on the mass of the particle (prop. to $(kT/m)^(1/2)$); and for heavy particles this effect may be significant. In fact, I'm interested in the case where $T \approx 10000K$

Comment: Notice that the argument is on room temperatures. The gas is neutral and no free electrons/ions  except those from collisions from the very high tail of the maxwell distribution. At T=10.000 you are at the plasma range , i.e. a gas of ions and electrons.http://www.uccs.edu/~tchriste/courses/PHYS549/549lectures/plasma.html "Since 1 eV corresponds to about 11,600 K, it is typically not practical to achieve ionization by thermal processes. Instead we rely on electron collisions with atoms"

Comment: @Pigeon  sorry , no. Would have to search the net.